# How to save downloadImageurl to firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm Trying to add my download image url to firestore as soon as I pressed an button. But instead of storing an url it stores "Instance of Future"

I've tried the following code.

For Storing an image to storage:

```
 Future uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(BuildContext context) async {
StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('uploads/$name');
StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_imageFile);
StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;  }
```

And this to get image url:

```
Future<void> getImageFromStorage() async {
final ref = _storage.ref().child('uploads/$name');
var url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
_downloadUrl = url.toString();
print('The URL is : $_downloadUrl');
return url; }
```

And using this functions as :

```
   onPressed: () {
                  uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(context);
                  if (doctorsName != null &&
                      doctorsPost != null &&
                      doctorsDegree != null) {
                    
                    _firestore.collection('Doctors Details').add({
                      'Name': doctorsName,
                      'Degree': doctorsDegree,
                      'Post': doctorsPost,
                      'URL': _downloadUrl, // Storing URL
                    });
                  }
                  
                  setState(() {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => Doctors(),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
```

I tried a lot but I can't fix this. I think I've mentioned my problem clearly. I'm now waiting for your help.
Thank You !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `uploadImageToFirebaseStorage` is marked as `async`, you need to `await` for it to be finished before you can use the resuls:

```
await uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(context);
...
```